# Create an subquery alias to use it in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create something like an alias to SQL subquery so I can use it like a plain SQL field. For example, I've got 3 tables: `user`, `user_comments` and `user_comment_answers`. If I want to get count of all answers to comments of current user, I'll do something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as comment_answers_count
  FROM user_comment_answers
  WHERE user_comment_id IN (SELECT id FROM user_comments WHERE user_id = :id)
```

Now I want to make Laravel treat this as a plain field of `user` table, so I can simply do stuff like this:

```
echo Auth::user()->comment_answer_count
```

or like this

```
$popularUsers = User::where('comment_answer_count', '>=', 100)
```

How can I achieve this in Laravel 5.4?

Comment: view this link hope it will help
http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-how-to-make-subquery-in-select-statementexample.html

Comment: @recoverymen thanks, but I know about raw queries. What I want is to incapsulate this subquery somewhere in SQL table or model and use it by alias just like any other plain SQL field.

Comment: sorry i am not clear what you want to achieve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with an SQL View creation like this:

```
CREATE VIEW user_with_comments AS
SELECT user.*, (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
    FROM user_comment_answers
    WHERE user_comment_id IN (SELECT id FROM user_comments WHERE user_id = user.id)
) as comment_answers_count
FROM user
```

I guess this is even possible to overload Eloquent methods to read from one table and write to another one, as this particular SQL View is read-only, but in my case read-only access is enough, so I've just set up another model `UserWithComments` and finally can use it like

```
$popularUsers = UserWithComments::where('comment_answer_count', '>=', 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$users = Auth::withCount('comments')->get();
```

Now all users have a `comments_count` property

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user->comments_count;
}
```

Assuming you defined the relationship in the `User` and `Comment` models.

**Update**

According to your first comment, what you want is an accessor

```
public function getCommentAnswerCountAttribute($value) {
     //define your query here 
}
```

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Hope this gives you a hint in finding your solution

Comment: Actually, this is the way of getting `comments_count`, not `comment_answer_count`. Table `user_comment_answers` have no direct relationship with table `user`, so this method wont work. However, this is only an example and my actual case has way more complicated query.

Comment: Good point, this solves part of the task. I still can't use `comment_answer_count` in `where` clause, but I can simply access it from model.